# Emberjs one way & two way bindings?

Tags: ember.js

Lets say I want that my page's title will change depending on a really simple field what is the Ember way of doing it?

I didn't really understand the bindings in Ember, do I have to create an object even if all I need is just 1 field?

Does Ember support two way bindings? if it does so how can I constrain the bindings to one-way only?

I think i'm a bit confused with Ember-data & regular Ember, when I use Ember-data do I need to care about bindings at all?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a little vague (or I just don't fully understand what you're asking), so I'll shotgun approach and we can narrow down as you ask more questions.

Preface: Ember Data is a client side record management library, Ember works completely fine without it.

### Title

A page's title is a little tricky since it's kind of out of the scope of the viewable dom, but the best way to handle it would be with an observer.  In the example below, as the `title` property changes inside of my application controller I'm setting the document.title.

```
App.ApplicationController = Em.Controller.extend({
  title:undefined,
  watchTitle: function(){
    document.title = this.get('title');
  }.observes('title')
  
})
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/haducafu/1

### Computed Properties

Ember does support one way bindings (though rarely do you need to care about bindings).  More often you want to care about dependent properties.  eg if property a has changed, property b should be updated etc. In the case below, b is a computed property that depends on a, if a changed, b is dirty, and ember should re-computed it.

```
App.ApplicationController = Em.Controller.extend({
  a:'foo',
  b: function(){
    return 'Hello: ' + this.get('a');
  }.property('a')      
})
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/haducafu/2/edit

### Simple Binding

Additionally Ember can do just simple bindings (you can actually skip defining name, since ember would define it the first time it uses it).

```
App.ApplicationController = Em.Controller.extend({
  name:undefined       
});

<h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
Name: {{input value=name}}
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/haducafu/3/edit

### One Way/Read Only:

One way will take the value from its host property, unless you set it, if you set it it stops following the dependent property and becomes its own (not modifying the dependent property).

Read only will take values form the host property, and if you try and set it it will blow chunks.

```
App.ApplicationController = Em.Controller.extend({
  name:'billy',
  oneWay: Em.computed.oneWay('name'),
  readOnly: Em.computed.readOnly('name')
});
```

Try changing name first, they will all update, then change `oneWay` and it will diverge and never return, then change `readOnly` and it will throw errors.

Example: http://jsbin.com/haducafu/4/edit

Comment: Thanks i liked how you changed the title.
I want to do something like <p>Hello {{user-name}}<p><input type='text' value={{user-name}}></input> so when you change the textbox it will change the DOM

Comment: For sure, the 2nd or 3rd example will show examples of that.  and I'm working up a 4th of a true one way binding

Comment: Oh great im trying to get my head Emberlike im too used to the Angular way

Comment: I think they both are a lot of fun, both with a bit of a curve, but really cool technologies, best of luck!